# Drupal - Update manager Cannot create directory

Tags: drupal

This is my first attempt at using drupal and I am trying to add a module to my drupal page. I keep on getting this error when i try and install anything...

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check your installation folder rights.. modules are in folder sites/all/modules and that should be writable (at least if you are just testing it locally). To add module you can just download that module as zip from drupal.org and extract it to sites/all/modules then go to "modules" page in drupal admin panel and activate that module.

Comment: @Hardy - Yeah, I changed the permission rights for the folder, but every time that I do it again it comes up with an error for the next folder. I know that i can download and extract, but it would seem more efficient for me to be able to use the website installer... But I guess it doesn't matter how you get from point A to point B just as long as you get there, right?

Comment: Actually i have always installed modules "by hand" and that has been ok for me. But maby this helps you to get right permissions: https://drupal.org/node/244924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that stumble upon this in the future...

@Hardy was right with his first comment:

> Check your installation folder rights.. modules are in folder sites/all/modules and that should be writable (at least if you are just testing it locally). To add module you can just download that module as zip from drupal.org and extract it to sites/all/modules then go to "modules" page in drupal admin panel and activate that module.

and

> Actually i have always installed modules "by hand" and that has been ok for me. But maby this helps you to get right permissions: drupal.org/node/244924

I ended up just doing what he suggested (doing it manually) and it really was no big deal...

Also, here is the link that he provided: https://drupal.org/node/244924